# Шаблонизированные методы ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть Шаблонизированные методы `DisplayFor` и `EditorFor`. Их шаблон вывода можно изменять создавая DisplayTemplates и EditorTemplates директории. Но изменяются они по определенным критериям, например по типу обрабатываемых данных, или по имени класса, или по принудительному указанию имени шаблона. Меня интересует такой вопрос, а можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы все эти методы (понятное дело, разделяя типы Display и Editor) выводили все из одного шаблона не зависимо от имени класса, типа обрабатываемых данных и пр ? Я попробовал в каждой из этих директорий создать файл `Object` с описанием шаблона, но это не подействовало.
То есть, у меня есть в представлении 7 Эдиторов и 5 Дисплеев, они работают с разными типами данных и не удобно создавать для каждого типа свой шаблон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать частичные виды (PartialViews) вместо шаблонов и дисплеев, если ваша задача "не налезает" на стандартный механизм.

Точно так же, как никто не мешает добавить свои методы к хелперам через расширение или даже добавить свои хелперы через замену базового класса вида...

Answer (score 2):

Мне получилось сделать так, что в View привожу свойства к Object

```
Object prop = Model.Prop;
```

А потом уже вывожу

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => prop)
```

Иначе думаю, что не получится сделать. 
Ибо чтобы вызвался шаблон для Object, нужно чтобы неудачно прошли остальные проверки на соответствие, либо тип был Object.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит сделать адекватную иерархию наследования, а не городить костыли через object.